# How do I specify a margin based on device size?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an angular/bootstrap web app. I want to specify a left margin of 40 px on md, xl, lg devices and 0 px on sm device. I have tried to add a spacer in styles.scss as follows:

```
$spacer: 1rem;

.ml-6{
  margin-left:($spacer*2.5);
}
```

Then in my html I have something like

```
<div class="ml-md-6 ml-sm-0 ml-xl-6 ml-lg-6">
          //some code
      </div>
```

But, this does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.ml-6` this doesn't match any of the classes on your element.

Comment: @disinfor these a infixed classes for responsive support.

Comment: @Simplicius  Oh, that's right! Apparently I've been working too long today. It was just being set wrong.

Comment: @disinfor. No shame ;D

Answer (score 1):

You can add new sizes to the `$spacers` map in sass.

This is the original `$spacer` vars/map in `_variables.scss`...

```
$spacer: 1rem !default;
$spacers: () !default;
$spacers: map-merge(
  (
    0: 0,
    1: ($spacer * .25),
    2: ($spacer * .5),
    3: $spacer,
    4: ($spacer * 1.5),
    5: ($spacer * 3)
  ),
  $spacers
);
```

So to add a `6th` size to this map you would need to add...

```
$spacers: map-merge(
  (
    6: ($spacer * 2.5)
  ),
  $spacers
);
```

...and including or importing it after the `_functions.scss`, `_variables.scss` and `_mixins.scss` files, but before all of bootstraps other sass files.

Like this...

```
// import bootstrap 4 src files
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$spacers: map-merge(
  (
    6: ($spacer * 2.5)
  ),
  $spacers
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
```

---

This below is not tested, but it would be logical to have your new `40px (2.5)` margin/padding spacing utility class located between the default `4` and `5` classes.

This would mean any current usages of `5` classes would need to be updated to `6`, and your new `40px (2.5)` class would be `5`.

```
$spacers: map-merge(
  (
    5: ($spacer * 2.5),
    6: ($spacer * 3)
  ),
  $spacers
);
```

Not sure the extent of this change beyond margin and padding utility classes. Like I say, not tested.